# How can I manually open the gas cap on a 2002 VW Golf?

Tags: vw, golf

The car has two switches on the bottom of the driver side door; one to open the gas cap, and one to open the trunk. Pressing the trunk button works fine, but pressing the gas cap button does not (it did before).

The car has other issues that the mechanic who looked at it didn't catch, and I'd like to take the car down (somewhere else) to have it looked at, but the Low Fuel light is on.

Is there some manual switch/lock/mechanism on the car that will allow me to pop the gas cap open?

Comment: have you looked behind the trim at the back of the gas filler? else disconnect the fuel filter in the engine bay and fit a funnel :)

Comment: have you tried approaching this with a friend: one to push the electric switch on the driver's door, and the other to wiggle and pull on the door over the fuel door?

Comment: @David Yeah, we tried that. Even tried sticking a small screwdriver in the gap between the panel and cap, and trying to gently move it, but it's not budged, and I don't want to make it worse by trying to pry too hard.

Comment: did you try pushing on the fuel door instead of just pulling?

Comment: @David Yes. Pushing, Pulling, top, bottom, sides.

Comment: Can you get to it from the backside, either by removing interior pieces of coming up from underneath the body?